# CRM 2011 Service Connection Issue With CallerID

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have an application that connects to the CRM 2011 service.  When I attach to the service without a CallerID I can grab the data without error.  The hitch comes when I add the caller ID to the connection.  I receive this error message (might seem familiar):

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the
>   exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the
>   server trace logs.  Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Retrieve(String entityName,
>   Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveCore(String
>   entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet) at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Retrieve(String
>   entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet) at
>   Hanlon.Data.CRM.DataObjectBase.Retrieve(Guid identity) at
>   Hanlon.Data.CRM.Advisor.Fill(Guid advisor_identity) at
>   HypotheticalReportCrmSite.HypotheticalReport.AcceptanceWorkFlow()

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening or how I can find out what the error is more specifically?  The application works on both Test and User Acceptance servers but blows up on Production.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there are a number of reasons why this may work differently on different servers, some places to start looking would be the setup/installation/permissions on the different servers including CRM, SQL, Active Directory (although I might assume AD would be the same).

Is there any difference in the proxy used for the Prod server compared to that on the Test/UAT systems?
Are all the relevant versions of the .NET framework available on the Prod server?
Are the same assemblies installed in the GAC?
Is SQL more locked down for the Prod server?

Were the CRM installations on the Prod server completed according to the same specifications as the Test and UAT servers? Were they installed by the same party?

Again, these are all just ideas, but it would seem that the differences between the servers would be the place to look and the installations of the key products would be a good place to start, followed perhaps by looking at the .NET framework etc.

Apologies if the answer is quite generic, but as you have found the specific error doesn't appear to have revealed a smoking gun.

I'd be interested to know what you find.